# Trying to make bootable used in 14.04 for 16.04 but it does not boot

Tags: usb, upgrade

I was trying to make a boot-able in 14.04 for 16.04. But after completing, when I restart the system and try boot from USB it gets stuck and says `grub not found`.

Is anyone else also found the same problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: If you have the option to burn the iso to a cd do it. Sometimes bootable usb making software messes up newer OS's, but a bootable cd will always work.

Answer (score 0):

The Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is not working to create the bootable USB for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, for what reasons ever...

Try **UNetbootin** instead, it works flawless on all systems!

Download it from [here](https://unetbootin.github.io/), insatll it from the Softwarecenter or from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

The usage of UNetbootin is self-explainable, just give it a try.